# "L'un et l'autre" : Qu'est-ce que ça veut dire ?

Tags: sens, expressions, locutions

Que signifie la deuxième phrase: **"l'un et l'autre"** ?

> Elle n'est point donc la première option ni la deuxième option, elle est **l'un et l'autre**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***L'un et l'autre*** signifie « (à la fois) le premier et le deuxième », c'est-à-dire « les deux ». On doit utiliser ici ***l'une*** car *option* est un mot féminin:

> *Elle n'est point donc la première option ni la deuxième option, elle est **l'une et l'autre**.*

Signifie donc :

> Elle n'est donc pas la première option ni la deuxième, elle est les deux.

ou mieux :

> Ce n'est donc ni la première, ni la seconde option, c'est les deux.

---

***L'un et l'autre*** means "one and the other", i.e. "both". Here that should be ***l'une*** because *option* is feminine:

> *Elle n'est point donc la première option ni la deuxième option, elle est **l'une et l'autre**.*

translates to:

> It is therefore not the first option nor the second one, it is both of them.